# How to pass a flag (--privileged) to a dokku command?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I need to run a command passing the flag `--privileged` to the underlying `docker run`, is there a way to pass it using `dokku run`?

Answer (score 0):

just found out, one should use https://dokku.com/docs/advanced-usage/docker-options/, for ie:

```
dokku docker-options:add myapp deploy,run "--privileged"
```

This will add the flag `--privileged` when running `deploy` and `run`